# Wordpress JWT Authentication does not protect custom endpoints

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I installed the [JWT Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) and it basically works: I make a POST request to ***[mypage]/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token*** and I get back the correct JSON containing the token. So the plugin seems to be installed correctly.

Then I tried another endpoint: ***[mypage]/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/register*** and expected the request (without authorization header) to be **rejected** by the JWT Plugin since the documentation mentions:

> The wp-api-jwt-auth will intercept every call to the server and will
>   look for the authorization header, if the authorization header is
>   present, it will try to decode the token and will set the user
>   according with the data stored in it.

But to my surprise, the request worked!

This is how the endpoint is set up on the server:

```
register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'users/register', array(
'methods' => 'POST',
'callback' => 'wc_rest_user_reg_ep_handler',
));
```

I thought all endpoints are protected by the JWT Plugin?

I read about the permission_callback but I think this is just a method to check user permissions. Which I thought I do not need, because my understanding is that the plugin rejects all invalid requests without token anyway. So in my endpoint I should be sure that the user has a valid token, thats enough for me.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT:
I think I lack general understanding of the concepts here.
Can someone confirm my guess:
If I want to protect my custom endpoints via JWT authentication, I should add a permission_callback which just does the "is_user_logged_in" check. If the request was made with a JWT authentication token, then this call will return TRUE, otherwise false. In other words, is_user_logged_in validates the token via the JWT plugin. Is that assumption correct?